# TextField for input text and insert images in JavaFX chat application

Tags: java, image, textbox, chat, javafx-8

I am developing a chat application on JavaFX and I stuck with a little problem. In short, I want to have a possibility to insert an image(for example smiles) inside TextField which is intended for text input.But as I know, there is no possibility to insert images inside this element. Does JavaFX have some alternatives for that or maybe you know something else, what I can use for this?

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an inline image to the end of a string in a TextArea in JavaFX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712808/how-to-add-an-inline-image-to-the-end-of-a-string-in-a-textarea-in-javafx)

Comment: Nope,TextFlow can be used for displaying text but not for input.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use HTMLEditor. It supports styled text and other html features, which include adding images.
There is example of using HTMLEditor as inputField for chat:

```
package org.laptech.sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


    public class ChatFieldSample extends Application{

    private HTMLEditor htmlEditor;

    public void hideHTMLEditorToolbars() {
        htmlEditor.setVisible(false);
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            Node[] nodes = htmlEditor.lookupAll(".tool-bar").toArray(new Node[0]);
            for (Node node : nodes) {
                node.setVisible(false);
                node.setManaged(false);
            }
            htmlEditor.setVisible(true);
        });
    }


    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        htmlEditor = new HTMLEditor();
        hideHTMLEditorToolbars();
        htmlEditor.setHtmlText("Text<img src='urltosmile'/>Text Text Text");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(htmlEditor, 300, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I create htmlEditor and hide toolbar in method(hideHTMLEditorToolbars)
 The only, which I faced , was the problem of losing focus, when i handle keyEvents and setText there.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Nice idea actually,could you explain it a little more?