# JavaFX - Inline images in a Textfield/Textarea

Tags: user-interface, text, javafx

I'm looking to make a `TextArea` or `TextField` but I want the ability for custom emoitcons. There will be key words that the user can type which changes that keyword to an emoticon image in-line.

The more I started thinking about it, the more complicated it seemed. How do you treat images as text? I hope someone out there has an idea.

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> -->About Emoji icons

Tutorial on GuiGarage:

http://www.guigarage.com/2015/01/support-emojis/

Because the emojis are defined as unicode chars the can be part of any String or character array that supports unicode. For example in Java the String object supports unicode and therefore a String can contain emoji chars

> --> Using Costume Icons

Answer from **ItachiUchiha** using `TextFlow` you can add any icon:

[How to add an inline image to the end of a string in a TextArea in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712808/how-to-add-an-inline-image-to-the-end-of-a-string-in-a-textarea-in-javafx)

> -->Using JavaFX RichTextField

https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX

> --> A chat client and Server made in javaFX

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xr3chat/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just wanted to make sure though that we're on the same page. The images I want to put in are custom 'emojis'. They are not default unicode characters. Is that a problem? For example, if I drew a 25x25 red square in MS paint, I want to now put that red square inline in my chat program.

Comment: @HateField i edited the answer provided what you need.