# How to make a text editor with the insertion of images?

Tags: text, javafx-8, text-editor

I need to implement a text editor JavaFX, but I have a problem with the creation of the function of adding the image in the text editing area.

It's exactly that when you click the button it was possible to add an image as the screenshot:

[image]

Now, I tried to use WebView where I put TextArea code below:

```
    private WebView view;
private WebEngine engine;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    view = new WebView();
    engine = view.getEngine();
    engine.loadContent("<body><textarea id='content'></textarea><p id='ding' style='display:none;'></p></body>");
    view.setPrefHeight(240);

    Button btn = new Button("Click Me!");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            append();
            engine.executeScript(
                    "document.getElementById('ding').innerHTML=document.getElementById('content').value;"
            );
        }
    });

    Button btn2 = new Button("Click Me 2!");
    btn2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            append();
            engine.executeScript(
                    "document.getElementById('ding').innerHTML=document.getElementById('content').value;"
            );
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().addAll(view, btn, btn2);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

private void append() {
    Document doc = engine.getDocument();
    Element el = doc.getElementById("ding");
    String s = el.getTextContent();

    s += "<img src='http://bluebuddies.com/gallery/Historical_Smurfs/jpg/Smurfs_Historical_Figure_20506_Abraham_Lincoln.jpg'/>";
    el.setTextContent(s);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

After clicking the button adds to the text in the text area link to the photo but unfortunately TextArea This is not supported and when I wanted to use some html editor problem so that I will not have the opportunity to extract all the text correctly with the formatting.

I tried solutions such as RichTextFX but unfortunately he does not have the ability to add images. The HTML editor also did not meet my expectations because I have entered text later saved to a file, for example type: docx. extract text from this editor with formatting is unfortunately difficult.
Are there any other solutions to create word processing with advanced features in JavaFX?

Ideally it was that it could be solved with normal controls TextArea without the use of WebView.

Comment: Please post some code, otherwise no one will be able to provide help.

Comment: I'll try to just show the code that currently have.

Comment: :) Add it to your question, you won't get any answers if you don't show people that you've tried to solve the problem. Even if your code doesn't work you'll get help from others.

Comment: TextFlow is an option:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712808/how-to-add-an-inline-image-to-the-end-of-a-string-in-a-textarea-in-javafx#29713808

Comment: Yes, TextFlow has options for displaying the images but you can't write it as a TextArea.

Comment: you can check out the Text class, add multiple of them

Comment: I'm sorry @Super-califragilistic  but I do not understand your comment. :(